# angularjs with $scope data-binding works just once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-bindings

i've a form with a select box. It's populate with data from JSON where each row has many keys. My idea is to show Description field on select, track by ID and other values showed in label.

This is my code:

```
                <div>
                    <label>Level:</label>
                    <div><select ng-model="levelModel" ng-options="level.code for level in levels track by id" required></select></div>
                    <label>name:{{levelModel.name}}</label>
                    <label>desc:{{levelModel.desc}}</label>
                </div>
```

and this is JSON

```
    levels = [
        {id:1, code:"a-code", name:"a-name", desc:"a-desc"},
        {id:2, code:"b-code", name:"b-name", desc:"b-desc"},
        {id:3, code:"c-code", name:"c-name", desc:"c-desc"} ]
```

My problem is on changing data on select box, data-binding works just once assigning to label the init data and not the selected data, all the others times binding doesn't work.

I think the reason is that i'm injecting $scope. I've read some guide about using $scope.$apply but if i try to user $scope.$apply in my controller like this

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.levelModel.name = "test"; })
```

after a few seconds i receive **$rootScope:inprogr error**

This is my app.js with route

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when("/report",{
                          templateUrl:"/reportV.html",
                          controller:"reportController",
                          resolve:{
                                   levels: function(selectSrv){
                                       return selectSrv.select(table); } } })
            .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
```

and this is my controller

```
app.controller("reportController", ["$scope", "levels", function($scope,levels){

    $scope.levels = levels.data;
```

How can i resolve?

P.S. my code is simplified, the view is routed and inside resolve i run some services to receive data from db

Comment: Use `$timeout` instead of `$scope.$apply`

Comment: Be sure you've init "levelModel" in your controller and not only in your view

Comment: Can you show us how you assign the data to some variable inside your controller? Is there anything you do when it changes? Normally, what you try to achieve is pretty straight and forward and does not require any ``$scope.apply()``

Comment: i've update my questions with two code block. Thanks all

Comment: try <div><select ng-model="$parent.levelModel" ng-options="level.code for level in levels track by id" required></select></div>

Comment: @jithin doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: @AlonEitan i would like to avoid $timeout because in my form i've about 30 field and some of those are select nested to other select.  Regards

Comment: resolved! i don't know the reason, but i have to delete "track by" from ng-options.